# Steel Worm/Steel Wheel vs Steel Worm/Bronze Wheel

Tags: mechanical-engineering, gears, metallurgy, metals

I have a question regarding worm drives, specifically double-enveloping types:

1. Do steel worm/steel wheel combinations last longer than steel worm/bronze wheel or steel worm/brass wheel combinations? If one were to use hardened tool steel for both the worm and wheel?
2. Are they also stronger than steel/bronze or steel/brass drives?
3. How much stronger are they?

Note: I know little about the underlying science behind gear design, just curious.

Comment: There may be other characteristics (such as low friction, and consequently greater efficiency) that mean it makes sense to choose a pairing that does not have the maximum strength or lifetime

Comment: The rule of thumb that I know is if you have two metal parts sliding against each other, it's best if they're dissimilar materials.  AFAIK it's to reduce friction.

Comment: But what if you have an application where you absolutely need the maximum torque capacity? (Due to weight and size restrictions)